# awk if/else throws error

Tags: awk

I tried this single command on  a CSV file and it works well.

```
awk -F, '$44==0 {sum += $45 } END { print sum}' Consolidated.csv

8448089
```

Basically this looks at field `44` in a csv and if it matches, it sums up the values in field `45`.

I wanted to extend this logic when field `44` value varies between `0` and `4` and hence wanted to create an if-else condition by extending the above logic but it was not successful. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: One more thing your command doesn't put SUM of 45th field into 45th field as per your comment, rather it creates a variable and then you are printing it in END block of awk.

Comment: Your subject line is `awk if/else throws error` which implies you've tried something and it failed with an error message - why not share that with us so we can help you debug it? Also [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AND `&&` operator in your condition:

```
awk -F, '$44>=0 && $44<=4 {sum += $45 } END { print sum}' Consolidated.csv
```

If you wanted both sums (Where column 44 is equal to 0 and a sum where it's between 0 and 4) you can just toss another test{block} in there:

```
awk -F, '$44>=0 && $44<=4 {sum2 += $45 } $44==0 {sum += $45 } END { print sum, sum2}' Consolidated.csv
```